# $\int_{0}^{\pi} f(t) \sin (nt)\mathrm dt =0$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f(0)=0$ then show $f \equiv 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

This question is from a old NBHM Phd scholarship test paper and stuck on it for a long time, here goes the problem:

Let $f: [0,\pi] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $\int_{0}^{\pi} f(t)\sin (nt) \mathrm dt =0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f(0)=0$ then show $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: Why does the integral involving $\sin$ have something to do with this problem? I guess the condition may be $\int_{0}^{\pi}f(nt)dt = 0$ for all $n \geq 1$ or something like this?

Comment: I've edited the question now, sorry for inconvenience

Comment: My guess would be a Fourier transformation of the function should lead to the result

Comment: Please also add where you are stuck on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $0< a < b < \pi$, and let $s = 1_{[a,b]} - 1_{[-b,-a]} \in L_2[-\pi,\pi]$. Let $s_n = \sum_{|k|\le n} \langle e_k, s\rangle e_k$, where $e_k(t) = {1 \over 2 \pi} e^{i n t}$. Note that $s_n \to s$ (in $L_2[-\pi,\pi]$) and since $s$ is odd, we have
$s_n = \sum_{0< k\le n, k\text{ odd} } ( \langle e_{-k}, s\rangle e_{-k} + \langle e_k, s\rangle e_k ) = \sum_{0< k\le n, k\text{ odd} } \langle e_k, s\rangle (e_k  -e_{-k} )$.

Extend $f$ to $[-\pi,\pi]$ by letting $f(t) = 0$ for $t \in [-\pi,0)$.

Since $s_n$ is the sum of $\sin$s, we have $\langle f, s_n \rangle = 0$, from
which is follows that $\langle f, s \rangle = 0$.

In particular, $\int_a^b f(t) dt = 0$. Since $a,b$ were arbitrary, the desired result follows.

Comment: What do you mean by $1_{[a,b]}$ ?

Comment: In general, for some set $A$, we define $1_A(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \in A \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$.

Comment: Actually, it would have been much simpler to extend $f$ to be odd, and then use the assumption to show that $\langle f, e_k \rangle = 0$ which, along with completeness of $\{e_k\}_k$ shows that $f=0$ (in $L_2$), and continuity gives $f(t) = 0$ everywhere.